# Assert that an element disappears: waits for the the element

Tags: cypress

I have this code where it basically should click on a button and the window div[data-e2e-modal] should not be visible anymore. My CSS-Checker shows me that after click the modal window is gone.

```
.click({ force: true }).then(() => {
    cy.get('div[data-e2e-modal]').should('not.be.visible');
```

However, in cypress the message for the second line is:

```
AssertionError
Timed out retrying after 10000ms: Expected to find element: div[data-e2e-modal], but never found it.
```

This error message is above all wrong, as it should not find div[data-e2e-modal]. Unfortunately, the best assertion that the click worked, is checking for the the div[data-e2e-modal] to disappear. Any suggestion?

Also this does not work:

```
 cy.modal()
      .button('Apply')
      .click({ force: true }).then(() => {
        cy.get('div[data-e2e-modal]')
          .button('Apply')
          .should('not.be.visible');
```

});

Answer (score 1):

As of 6.0, cypress has mentioned this in their [Migration guide](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/migration-guide#Migrating-to-Cypress-6-0):

> Use .should('not.exist') to assert that an element does not exist in
> the DOM (not .should('not.be.visible'), etc).

So instead, you can try something like this:

```js
cy.get('buttonSelector').click({force: true})
cy.get('div[data-e2e-modal]').should('not.exist')
```